# Problems with calculator that answers are dynamically answered

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, calculator

Im working on a calculator app that outputs the answers as you type instead of tapping the equals button. So far everything works fine unless you add (or -,/,*) on a number thats already been calculated. For example, if i do 10 + 15 + 9 it gives me 169 instead of the correct answer (34). I think I know why this happens, but I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
     if (answer == NO) {

    saved1 = saved1 * 10 + digit;

    if ([self.screen.text  isEqual: @"0"] || operationClear == YES) {

        self.screen.text = number;

        operationClear = NO;

    }else{


        self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.screen.text, number];

    }


}else{

    saved2 = saved2 * 10 + digit;

    if (plus == YES) {

        answerr = saved1 + saved2;

        //saved1 = answerr;

        // saved2 = 0;

        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];

        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        self.screen.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:answerr]];



    }        
  } 
}
```

I believe the problem is when you hit the plus for the second time it just adds 9 onto the end of `saved2`. To solve this I tried making `saved1` equal the answer and made `saved2` equal zero this didn't work. 
Any ideas? If I'm doing this terribly wrong please tell me, I'm new to iOS development and want to do this the most efficient way possible. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, from your code it looks that you're using math to display the number after the user presses a new digit.

For instance if '1' is displayed and the user presses 2, you get '12' by doing 1 * 10 + 2

Perhaps a better way to do this would be to deal with strings for instance, when the user is inputting numbers

For instance, if '1' is displayed and the user presses '2', take the '2' string and add it to the '1' string:

```
NSString * displayString = calculatorDisplay.text; // display
NSString * userInputString = @"2"; 

calculatorDisplay.text = [displayString stringByAppendingString:userInputString];
```

Then, when you need a number, convert it to a number using this:

```
- (NSNumber *)numberFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    return [f numberFromString:string];
}
```

I know this changes things a bit, but I think it will be more consistent.  It also lets the user input things like decimals easily.

Comment: I originally had it like that actually, but I was told be numerous people that I should be doing it the way I'm doing it now. Im not sure what I'm going to end up doing. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, any reason?  How do you handle decimals?

Comment: I actually didn't get to that yet, I think i probably will go with your way, it seems that it will make things a lot simpler. How would i do the actual math this way though?

Comment: When you want a number that you can do math with, just do

Comment: Get the float value of your NSNumber by using its .floatValue property and do math against these values. Floats are better because things like 3 / 2 will give you 1 if '3' & '2' are int's if they are floats, you'd get 1.5